No output or input devices found on Kubuntu post upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04
After I upgraded to Kubuntu 24.04 the sound is not working anymore. It shows no output or input devices found.
I reinstalled pipewire using the following command.
sudo apt reinstall pipewire pipewire-bin pipewire-pulse
systemctl --user --now enable pipewire pipewire-pulse

It worked but then it stopped working altogether.
